# How do I interact with Maven goals using Eclipse/STS?

Tags: eclipse, maven, user-interface

I am learning Eclipse, and I'm trying to find out how to interact with Maven goals visually in Eclipse/SpringSource Toolsuite. In IDEA, there is a nice Maven menu on the right-hand side of the IDE that is put there by default - no extra user configuration is necessary to make this show up there.

How can I get the same thing in Eclipse? It seems weird that this is not enabled by default. I've looked in the "Window" section of the IDE and I also don't see it either. The only window dealing with Maven is the repository listings... which is not what I want.

Do people use the command line instead? How can I get the same thing that IDEA has?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If it is eclipse, get M2Eclipse plugin installed for your eclipse.
  Just go to Help -> Eclipse Market Place and try to Find "Maven
  Integration For Eclipse". In the results choose "Maven Integration
  For Eclipse" and install it.
- Then, if the project in your workspace is a Maven Project right click
  on it and choose Run As -> it will show you some default goals
  like clean, install, etc.. If you want to run other goals choose run 
  configurations and in the left part of the window, you will find an
  option Maven Build. Right click on it and select New -> then you will
  be prompted to choose the project and enter the goals you want to
  execute...

Comment: I actually had that installed. I had to say "convert to Maven project". This is weird because I used the maven eclipse:eclipse goal to create the project. Is this goal even safe to use? It seems to have made so many errors with the war and the context root too...

Comment: It turns out that deleting STS, my workspace, and all of my project file files and starting over solved the problem. I guess there must have been a bug with 2.9.0 of STS, because it works with 2.9.1 :/

Comment: yeah.. eclipse:eclipse goal is to convert the project to an eclipse project.. yes.. it is safe.. anywys.. glad it helped..